# SQL - selecting the first record found before a given date

Tags: sql

Say I have a table:

```
ID  DATE
1   2/1/12
2   3/1/12
3   1/1/12
4   4/1/12
```

How would I go about selecting the first date found when decrementing from a given date.

Example:  Find the last entry before 4/1/12, by date.  Return entry at SQL ID 2.

If this was added:

```
ID  DATE
5   3/2/12
```

Than the above example would return the entry at SQL ID 5.

How would I represent what I need in SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select top 1 ID, DATE
from table
where DATE < '4/1/12'
order by DATE DESC
```

Comment: @K'Leg yes me too but was trying to be as true to the op's example as I could

Answer (score 0):

other ideas: (in addition to Gratzy's)

select the MAX date where the date is less than the target date.

use a LAG function.