# Trying to retrieve the most recent previous entry in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the most recent entry in a table that's past a certain Event. The main table this concerns contains an ID for a user, the kind of event that happened as well as a timestamp.

This is where I am currently at:

```
SELECT cc.RefNo
    ,cc.Subcase
    ,ev.EventDate 
    ,evt.EventCode
    ,ev.Amount
    ,previousevent.EventCode as [previous Event]
    ,previousevent.previousdate as [date previous event]
  FROM event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
  JOIN CCase cc ON cc.ID = ev.CCaseID 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(ev.EventDate) as previousdate, evt.EventCode, CCaseID
                            FROM Event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
                            WHERE (evt.EventCode LIKE 'SI%' OR evt.EventCode LIKE 'SM%')
                            Group by CCaseID, evt.EventCode) as previousevent
  ON previousevent.CCaseID = cc.ID
  AND previousevent.previousdate < ev.EventDate
```

The output for this is giving me ALL previous Events (though no dupes for individual events, I assume). I am now looking for a way to get to the most recent one for each combination of RefNo, Subcase, EventDate and EventCode.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - selecting the first record found before a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839350/sql-selecting-the-first-record-found-before-a-given-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but perhaps the `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()` may help here

```
SELECT Top 1 with ties
       cc.RefNo
      ,cc.Subcase
      ,ev.EventDate 
      ,evt.EventCode
      ,ev.Amount
      ,previousevent.EventCode as [previous Event]
      ,previousevent.previousdate as [date previous event]
  FROM event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
  JOIN CCase cc ON cc.ID = ev.CCaseID 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(ev.EventDate) as previousdate, evt.EventCode, CCaseID
                            FROM Event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
                            WHERE (evt.EventCode LIKE 'SI%' OR evt.EventCode LIKE 'SM%')
                            Group by CCaseID, evt.EventCode) as previousevent
  ON previousevent.CCaseID = cc.ID
  AND previousevent.previousdate < ev.EventDate
  Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By RefNo, Subcase, EventCode Order By EventDate Desc)
```

Comment: I think it should work, and if so, that's even simpler then my answer...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Virtually the same thing.  I just like the WITH TIES because there is no extra field.  However TOP (1+n) gets a little tricky

Comment: This solution worked! I did have to change `Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By RefNo, Subcase, evt.EventCode Order By EventDate Desc)` to `Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By RefNo, Subcase, evt.EventCode Order By previousdate Desc)` but the results all look good.

Comment: @Haris Happy it helped.  Even happier that you "got it" so that you can adjust as needed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do it is with a cte and row_number:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT cc.RefNo
        ,cc.Subcase
        ,ev.EventDate 
        ,evt.EventCode
        ,ev.Amount
        ,previousevent.EventCode as [previous Event]
        ,previousevent.previousdate as [date previous event]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cc.RefNo ,cc.Subcase ,ev.EventDate, evt.EventCode ORDER BY previousevent.previousdate DESC) AS rn
      FROM event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
      JOIN CCase cc ON cc.ID = ev.CCaseID 
      JOIN (SELECT MAX(ev.EventDate) as previousdate, evt.EventCode, CCaseID
                                FROM Event ev JOIN EventTemplate evt ON ev.EventTemplateID = evt.ID
                                WHERE (evt.EventCode LIKE 'SI%' OR evt.EventCode LIKE 'SM%')
                                Group by CCaseID, evt.EventCode) as previousevent
      ON previousevent.CCaseID = cc.ID
      AND previousevent.previousdate < ev.EventDate
)

SELECT cc.RefNo
        ,cc.Subcase
        ,ev.EventDate 
        ,evt.EventCode
        ,ev.Amount
        ,previousevent.EventCode as [previous Event]
        ,previousevent.previousdate as [date previous event]
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```